# how to update a property of a specific object in arrays of object in react using setstate

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I want to update a specific value of specific object of array(array of object) using setState in react context !

here is what i am doing

```
getFieldData = (inputType, data, id) => {
       const index = this.state.sharedPeople.findIndex(a => a.id == id);
       this.setState({ sharedPeople: [this.state.sharedPeople[index], { email: data }] })}
```

am not able to update the value by doing this it malfunctions here !!
Please guide me the better and correct way of doing this behaviour !

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
    getFieldData = (inputType, email, id) => {

      let sharedPeople = this.state.sharedPeople.map((person => {
        if(person.id === id){
           person.email = email
      }
      return person
    })

setState({sharedPeople})

}
```